# How to create dynamic content flash object on the fly using ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, flash, swfobject

Doesas anyone know how to create an aspx page with a Flash object inside? And how to change the content of the Flash object? Thanks

e.g:

```
________________  ________
|Textbox        | |Submit|
----------------  --------

    _________________________
   |                         |
   |                         |
   |      FLASH OBJECT       |
   |_________________________|
```

I have a textboxt and a button. If I change the textbox value with string value (example="Hello World") and I press the submit button, it will replace a "FLASH OBJECT" string on the flash object into "Hello World".. anyone know how to do that?? thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash has a JavaScript API you can use to get/set values in the Flash object. See http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashjscommand/ for an example.